# WebServices on Unity, Dll, compatibility with .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, unity-game-engine, dll

I'm trying to use web services on unity.
I used svcutil to generate a proxy class, however the proxy class was using "System.Threading.Tasks".

I noticed that System.Threading.Tasks wasn't aviable on .Net 3.5.
So I went to player setting and I changed [to .Net 4.x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw3oR.jpg)

But now I have an other issue, and I cannot find a way to fix it, I need to use System.Web.dll and System.Web.Services.dll to make my web service work, however, the dll that are include in Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0 [are all targets for .Net 3.5.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eSa5.jpg)

So that mean I cannot use them on .Net 4.x

I've been looking for quiet long and was unable to find any answer.
I can add the code to the proxy class here if it's require, but I don't think it would be useful. Should I download those dll somewhere? 
Anyone ever seen thoses issues somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong dll version.

Once you change `Api Compatibility Level` to Net 4.x, you have to copy the `System.Web.dll` and `System.Web.Services.dll` files from `<UnityInstallationDirectory>\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\4.5` to your `<Project>\Assets` path.

That's it. Restart Visual Studio and Unity.

Comment: Oh i see, it was on \MonoBleedingEdge\ and not mono. My bad i guess i should have look every folder.
Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: It used ti be the mono folder but that change after .NET 4.x support. Anything .NET 4.x, you should look in the MonoBleedingEdge folder

Answer (score 1):

There is another method of linking missing libraries as described in [this unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/dotnetProfileAssemblies.html).

Create a file called *csc.rsp* and put these 2 lines in it:

```
-r:System.Web.dll
-r:System.Web.Services.dll
```

And yes, you better set compatibility level to .NET 4.x
You also might want to restart Unity or VS in some cases.